# How to make this block correctly in html?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1496527996/5dd30ca7/17453438.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 0%;">
 <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 292px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, help with this UI. I have got this [UI picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCF6k.jpg). I don't know how to make these lines. Used more 1200px. Maybe you've seen similar examples? How do it? Thank you!!!

Comment: What have tried so far ? Any code to share ?

Comment: You need to have made some sort of attempt at this. Share that code with us and let us know what you tried and didn't work and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Sorry! I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements on the paragraphs to draw the lines.

```css
.line.col-md-4 {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.line.col-md-4:before {
  content: '';
  background: purple;
  width: 1px;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tr:before {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.tl:before {
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.bl:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.br:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.tr:before, .bl:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tl:before, .br:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1496527996/5dd30ca7/17453438.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 0%;">
 <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 292px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 line tl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 line tr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container circle">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 line bl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 line br">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid corrupti distinctio, doloribus quia facilis mollitia fugiat expedita dignissimos consectetur culpa illo et, inventore ipsam deserunt odit quaerat sed sunt? Eius!</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```